# Understanding printing bytes in the Python interactive interpreter

Tags: python, terminal, byte, ansi-escape

I've stumbled upon what I can only describe as a bug in the interactive interpreter for Python. While the bug is rather inconsequential I felt that it was an interesting problem, and a good chance to learn something about python, low level computing, and debugging.

The problem occurs here:

```
pic = open("blurry.jpg", "rb")
data = pic.read()
for byte in data:
    print byte
```

this results in...

```
#prints the entire file byte by byte_
?

0
?
?
>>> 1;2c
```

Now after this is done I find that  [  ] { } \ @ ^ have been replaced by Ä, Å, ä, å, ö, É, 'Ü' respectively. Interestingly though, they still maintain functionality. For example `list = Ä1,2,3,4Å` raises no errors. Furthermore, and possibly more interesting... this behavior continues even after I quit the interpreter and go back into bash.

Also, I can only recreate this behavior when using a specific image, which I've hosted here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xWTH1.jpg

I haven't got a clue as to where I would begin to analyze a problem like this, so I was hoping someone here could lend some insight.

Thanks as always!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is not a bug with Python, this is your terminal switching to an alternate charset. Run `reset` at the shell prompt to fix this.

Comment: Oh haha! What is causing this then? How does printing the contents of the picture result in changing the charset?

Comment: @Pete: The terminal driver is set up to intercept specific bytes and switch upon receipt. That picture contains those bytes.

Comment: Huh, interesting. What exactly do you mean by that? Its not like there has been a command executed or anything is it? So is terminal seeing the charset used and changing accordingly? Where could I learn more about this?

Comment: So the mere fact that some of these escape sequences are in the picture causes this? Wow thats really cool. I've been looking at some stuff you can do with it.... I had no idea! :P  While I do feel silly that this was so easily explained, I've definitely learned something here... Thanks